# How to run long running service in android in all devices greater than api level 16 not from alarm manager

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

How to run long running service in android in all devices greater than api level 16. I have written below code for the service but somehow not working for api 17 - 19. and its working for all devices above 19 api level. Please have a look and suggest me how to do it. I am new android and writing service for the first time.

below is code

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    public int counter = 0;

    public ViksitService(Context applicationContext) {
        super();
        Log.i("HERE", "here I am!");
    }

    public MyService() {
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        startTimer();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i("EXIT", "ondestroy!");
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent("MyService_RESTART_SERVICE");
        sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
        stoptimertask();
    }

    private Timer timer;
    private TimerTask timerTask;
    long oldTime = 0;

    public void startTimer() {
        //set a new Timer
        timer = new Timer();

        //initialize the TimerTask's job
        initializeTimerTask();

        //schedule the timer, to wake up every 1 second
        timer.schedule(timerTask, 1000, 1000); //
    }

    /**
     * it sets the timer to print the counter every x seconds
     */
    public void initializeTimerTask() {
        timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                Log.i("in timer", "in timer ++++  " + (counter++));
            }
        };
    }

    /**
     * not needed
     */
    public void stoptimertask() {
        //stop the timer, if it's not already null
        if (timer != null) {
            timer.cancel();
            timer = null;
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

below is broadcast reciever :

```
public class ServiceRestarterBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(ServiceRestarterBroadcastReceiver.class.getSimpleName(), "Service Stops! Oooooooooooooppppssssss!!!!");
        context.startService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));;
    }
}
```

below is manifest :

```
<service
    android:name=".services.MyService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">

</service>
<receiver
    android:name=".services.ServiceRestarterBroadcastReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="MyService_RESTART_SERVICE"/>
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: what is the error in 17-19?

Comment: problem here is onDestroy method of service class is not able to broadcast the intent     Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent("MyService_RESTART_SERVICE");
        sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);

Comment: i can see logger EXIT is getting printed but service is not restarting.

Comment: is your receiver receiving the broadcast?

Comment: nope that is exactly problem here

Comment: You can do it using android.os.ResultReceiver as well..